# Как работает XML парсинг средствами Xpath из JAXP?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Господа, я изучаю различия и особенности, а также плюсы и минусы разных инструментов для парсинга из *JAXP*. Я уже знаю, что *DOM* строит узловую модель парсируемого *XML* документа, загружая ее в *ОП*, из-за чего растет скорость и удобство обработки/поиска данных в целевом *XML* файле.

*Sax* же, работает последовательно, скорее всего побайтово, кэшируя байты в ноды и обрабатывает *Handler*'ом, который реализуется программистом под конкретный документ. В результате скорость и удобство обработки средние, зато *ОП* потребляется меньше.

Так вот вопросы:

- как действует `Xpath` парсер?
- Он тоже загружает парсируемый *XML* документ в *ОП*?
- Какие у него плюсы и минусы относительно *SAX* и *DOM*?

**P.S.**

На мысль, что `Xpath` парсер тоже грузит документ в файл, натолкнул следующий демо-код на *Java*.

Четвертая строка в внутри `try-catch`, где получаем документ doc:

```
try {
        File inputFile = new File("src/main/resources/courses.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);

        XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        String expression = "progschool/course";
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node nNode = nodeList.item(i);
            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                System.out.println("Id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
                System.out.println("Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Teacher : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("teacher").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Hours : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("hours").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Day : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("day").item(0).getTextContent());
            }
        }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Я, честно говоря, не могу понять Вашего вопроса.. Куда что XPath грузит? какой документ? в какой файл? По коду вы отпарсили XML в DOM, затем сделали выражение XPath которое должно было найти все узлы `course`..  в чем проблема?

Comment: Работает ли Xpath поиск без парсинга в DOM и как это делается? Как вообще работает Xpath и требует ли ОП как DOM?

Comment: Как без DOM ? SAX умеет только вперед, а у XPath есть выражения которые требуют посмотреть что было до этого. В интернетах есть имплементации подмножества XPath на SAX.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Значит Xpath в отличии от чистого DOM-подхода лучше только удобством выборки данных из XML-документа.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath - язык выражений, позволяющий обрабатывать значения, соответствующие модели данных [XDM](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel-31/). XPath может выбрать **любой** узел во **всем** документе. Соответственно, документ обязан быть **полностью** загружен в память.

В чём разница между DOM и XDM. Кратко: модель данных XDM специально предназначена для быстрого доступа к узлам с помощью осей XPath.

> как действует Xpath парсер?

XPath - не парсер. Это язык запросов, потребляющий уже *готовую* модель данных. При этом не важно, с помощью какого парсера - SAX, StAX или что-то ещё, - была создана эта модель (готовый документ в памяти).

> Он тоже загружает парсируемый XML документ в ОП?

Да, полностью.

> Какие у него плюсы и минусы относительно SAX и DOM?

Вопрос не имеет смысла. Нельзя сравнивать язык выражений запросов, парсер и модель данных.

> Sax ... работает последовательно ... В результате скорость ... обработки средние

Не совсем так. Вы не учитываете, что обработка с применением потоковых парсеров производится *одновременно* с парсингом. Поэтому, если сравнивать с обработкой xml с применением DOM/XPath, то нужно учитывать также время *предварительной* загрузки всего документа в память.
При обработке больших xml потоковые парсеры обычно вне конкуренции по скорости.

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ. Надо будет мне также прочитать про StAX-парсер. Я как-то видел статью на одном IT-ресурсе о том, как автор при размере файла 1Gb+ нашел рациональным именно подход StAX + Xpath.Непонятно только как удается реализовать такую связку SAX/StAX + Xpath, если условием работы Xpath-процессора является готовая, целостная модель в памяти (Это)

Comment: @IngeniousTom - Да, можно загружать лишь часть данных и к ней обращаться с помощью XPath. Естественно, это возможно не всегда. Структура данных должна подходить для такого сценария.

Answer (score 0):

Стоит сказать, что xpath, dom и sax никак сами по себе не завязаны на jaxp, это отдельные спецификации w3c. Xpath-процессор не обязательно должен работать через DOM. Вот список реализаций, работающих поверх SAX https://stackoverflow.com/a/16416796/5506820. Он даже не обязательно должен работать поверх SAX. Другое дело, что реализация поверх DOM наиболее проста, а реализация поверх SAX или другого парсера, не строящего полные модели xml-докуентов в памяти, часто быстрее в работе (время работы xpath поверх sax против времени парсинга в DOM-дерево + xpath поверх DOM) и ест меньше памяти (так как не хранит всю модель документа). Но стоит заметить, что результатом работы данных процессоров может быть только примитивный тип, вроде строки или числа, и никаких Node и NodeSet (мы же хотим не использовать DOM). Плюс ты можешь попасть на ограничения конкретной реализации, которая не всегда соответствует полному стандарту w3c или реализует не самую последнюю версию этого стандарта.
Собственно внутри многих xslt-процессоров как раз таки стоит xpath-процессор, работающий поверх sax.

Comment: Спасибо за дополнительную информацию.